# Reversing a '\0' terminated C string in place?

Tags: c, pointers, reverse, dereference

I have some conceptual questions about reversing a null terminated C string, and clarification questions about the nature of pointers.

The input might be

```
char arr[] = "opal";
```

and the code:

```
void reverse(char *str) {  /* does *str = opal or does *str = o since the pointer str is type char? */

    char* end  = str; /* what is the difference between char* end and char *end? and is *end pointing to opal now? */

    char tmp;

    if (str) {  /* if str isn't null? */
        while (*end) 
            ++end; 
    }
    --end; /* end pointer points to l now */

    while (str < end) {     /* why not *str < *end? is this asking while o < l? */
        tmp = *str; /* tmp = o */

        *str++ = *end; /* what is the difference between *str++ and ++str? does *str++ = l? */
        *end-- = tmp; /* *end points to o */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your are literally passing `"opal"` that would be undefined behavior since you not allowed to modify a string literal.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour what would you pass then?

Comment: A char array, `char arr[] = "opal";`.

Comment: To understand C pointers, I would never think char* as string, I would think of it just a memory address. But for the most times a char* pointer would point to a memory address containing a NULL terminated string.

Comment: The test `if (str) {` provides no safety.  If `str` is `NULL`, then `end` is `NULL and the next LOC is `--end` --> seg fault.  Better to `if (str == NULL) return;`

Comment: @chux valid point; I updated my answer to reflect that and some related thoughts that occurred to me after reading your comment.

Comment: Newer versions of gcc will warn you for passing string literals to functions that take something other than `const char*`. It is covered under `-Wwrite-strings`, and it is enabled by ***default*** in the g++ front-end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lots of questions... trying to capture answers to each:

> > /* does *str = opal or does *str = o since the pointer str is type char? */

`*str` is `'o'` since it points at the first character

> > /* what is the difference between char* end and char *end? and is *end pointing to opal now? */

There is no difference between `char *end` and `char* end`. It gets trickier when you write

```
char* a, b;
```

since this is equivalent to

```
char *a, b;
```

and not, as you might think

```
char *a, *b;
```

This is why it's cleaner to write `char *end;`.

And `end` is pointing to `opal` now - `*end` is `'o'`.

> > if (str) {  /* if str isn't null? */

Yes - testing that you did not get passed a NULL pointer

To test that you did not get passed a string of length 0, you would have to test `*str` (after testing that `str` is not NULL, otherwise you get a segmentation error for "daring to look at *NULL")

> > while (str < end) {     /* why not *str < *end? is this asking while o < l? */

Testing the pointers - one is moving towards the end, the other is moving back. When you meet in the middle you stop; otherwise you do the swap twice, and there will be no net effect...

> > ```
> >  *str++ = *end; /* what is the difference between *str++ and ++str? does *str++ = l? */
> > ```

You first copy the value of `*end` to `*str`, then you increment the `str` pointer. If you put `++str`, you increment first, then use it. And that would mean that you put the `l` in place of the `p` instead of in place of the `o`.

**edit** one critique on your code (going beyond the questions you asked, and responding to a comment from @chux): when you test for `if(str){}` you really need an `else return;` statement, since you actually do `end--;` and then use `*end`. Pretty sure that `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` is almost always an invalid address...

If you in fact were testing for `if(*str!='\0')` then you should still just return (an empty string is "irreversible" - or rather, it doesn't need anything to be considered reversed).

By the way, I much prefer making the condition explicit (like I did just then); not only does it show your intention more clearly, but the compiler might actually complain if you did `if(str!='\0')` or `if(*str != NULL)` since the types you are comparing are incompatible. This means you will have code that is more robust, more readable, and more likely to do what you intended.

Comment: If I could, I'd +1 you again for the comments about explicit testing in the last paragraph.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - very likely I learned the importance of that approach some time in the last year by reading one of your answers / comments. Yes, I am mostly here to learn, although I do so by attempting to answer questions. Thanks for the compliment!

Answer (score 2):

> does *str = opal or does *str = o since the pointer str is type char?

`str` is pointer to first element of `opal`, i.e, it is pointer to first letter `o`. So, `*s` means , you are dereferencing the `s` (the first address) hence it is `'o'`.

> what is the difference between char* end and char *end? and is *end pointing to opal now?

There is no difference. No. It is `end` that is pointing to `opal`, i.e, its first element now.

> if str isn't null?

Yes.

> end pointer points to l now

Yes. It is now pointing to the last letter of the word.

> what is the difference between *str++ and ++str? does *str++ = l?

`*str++` means `str` will incremented after the value dereferenced `str` pointing to. `++str` simply the pre-incrementation of `str`.
`*str++ =` assign the value to the dereferenced variable before incrementing `str`.

Comment: I didn't down vote, someone else must have. I just edited the question to pass `char arr[] = "opal";`

Comment: Good answer Professor haccks. +1

Answer (score 2):

> does *str = opal or does *str = o since the pointer str is type char?

`*str` dereferences the pointer, which is of type `char*`, so the type you get is `char`.  That `char` will be the value pointed to by `str`, which will be `'o'`.

> what is the difference between char* end and char *end?

Nothing.

> and is *end pointing to opal now?

Yes, well, close.  `end` is pointing to exactly the same adddress as `str`, which is the start of your string of characters.  `*end` is a character type, not a pointer.  Its value will be `'o'`.

> if str isn't null?

Correct, doing a boolean test on a pointer is a standard test.  It evaluates to a 'true' value if the pointer is not null and 'false' otherwise.  Note that this is not the same as a zero value.  The C standard allows any value to represent a null address.

> why not *str < *end? is this asking while o < l?

No, it is comparing the actual memory address.  It says to loop while `str` points to an earlier part of the string than `end`.  You'll notice that during the loop, `str` increases, and `end` decreases.  So eventually they will pass eachother or meet at the same character (*ie* the middle of the string).

> what is the difference between *str++ and ++str? does *str++ = l?

`str++` is applied first, which increments `str` and returns its previous value, then the `*` unary operator derferences to give the character at that old position.  Yes, the first time around, the `'l'` from `end` will be assigned to the beginning of the string (where `str` used to point before it was incremented).  The `tmp` is used to carry the old character and assign it to `end`.  This is a standard 'swap' operation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `reverse` is called like this:

```
char str[] = "opal";
reverse(str);
```

And is assigned to memory, as an example, like this:

```
Memory Address:   100   101   102   103   104
Memory Value:    ['o'] ['p'] ['a'] ['l'] ['\0']
```

The following, regarding addresses, are true:

1. `str + 0 == &str[0] == 100`
2. `str + 1 == &str[1] == 101`
3. `str + 2 == &str[2] == 102`
4. `str + 3 == &str[3] == 103`
5. `str + 4 == &str[4] == 104`

And the following, regarding values, are true:

1. `*(str + 0) == str[0] == 'o'`
2. `*(str + 1) == str[1] == 'p'`
3. `*(str + 2) == str[2] == 'a'`
4. `*(str + 3) == str[3] == 'l'`
5. `*(str + 4) == str[4] == '\0'`

Regarding `NULL`, when a pointer is uninitialized, that is, not pointing to valid memory, it should be assigned the value of `NULL`, which in most cases is the address 0.  Consider the following:

```
char *str = NULL;
reverse(str);
```

When the following expression is evaluated:

```
if(str)
```

It will evaluate to `FALSE`.  Inside `reverse`, it should (you should fix it) immediately `return` because using a pointer with an address of `NULL` will result in undetermined behavior, such as a segmentation fault.

Assigning the address of `str` to `end` when its address is `NULL` and then decrementing it:

```
--end;
```

Will result in undetermined behavior.

Comment: This doesn't cover all the questions in the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right, but if you can understand this, the answers to the other questions will become evident.

Comment: @Awwww. No. But agreed with Jonathan Leffler :D

Comment: @haacks I expanded my answer.  But you're right.  There's are enough questions in the question to have a write an entire chapter to cover it all. :-D

Answer (score 1):

> does `*str = opal` or does `*str = 'o'` since the pointer `str` is type `char`?

It's both. I know it's confusing, but here is what's going on: in C, a pointer can be interpreted in two ways - either literally, i.e. as a pointer to a single item (`char` in this case) or as a pointer to the beginning of a sequence of items of the same type. In the later case the end of the sequence is to be defined. There are three ways to know where the sequence ends - by knowing the length explicitly, by knowing the ending pointer, or by placing a "terminator" item at the end of the sequence. In case of C strings, a special character `'\0'` called "null terminator" is used to terminate the sequence.

> what is the difference between `char* end` and `char *end`? and is `*end` pointing to opal now?

There is absolutely no difference - they both point to the same place. The placement of asterisk does not matter.

> if `str` isn't `null`?

Correct

> `end` pointer points to `'l'` now

Absolutely!

> why not `*str < *end`? is this asking `while o < l`?

You are comparing locations in memory, not characters they point to. This is asking for the pointers to not "cross" each other, because the two are going toward the center from both ends of the string.

> `tmp = o`

On the first iteration, it is. On the second iteration, it points to `'p'`

> what is the difference between `*str++` and `++str`? does `*str++` = `'l'`?

The `++str` expression increments the value of the pointer, and evaluates to the value of the *pointer* after the increment; the `*str++` expression increments the value of the pointer, and evaluates to the value of the *character* that was pointed to by the pointer *before* the increment.